# Parameter to define a type of class

Tags: php

I have a constructor that asks for a type of class, but it doesn't define that as a type hint. You are able to pass anything you want to it, and it will accept it. Is there a way to pass a class type to the constructor, and in the `add()` method it only accepts that type?

Currently what I have, is the ability to pass anything to the constructor such as an `int`, `string`, `bool`, etc. Is there a way to make it so that the constructor only accepts class types?

```
class Main{

    protected $items = [];
    protected $type  = '';

    public function __construct($type){
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function add($object){
        if($object instanceof $this->type){
            $this->items[] = $object;
        }
    }
}

class Test{}
class Awesome{}

$main1 = new Main(Test::class);
$main2 = new Main(Awesome::class);

// Successful:
$main1->add(new Test());
// Fail:
$main1->add(new Awesome());


// Successful:
$main2->add(new Awesome());
// Fail:
$main2->add(new Test());
```

If I were to do it in C# it would look something like this:

```
Main main1 = new Main<Test>();
Main main2 = new Main<Awesome>();
```

Basically it says that `add()` will only allow instances of `Test`. Is there a way to do some

Comment: So you just want to make sure that the class which you pass to the constructor exists?

Comment: I basically want to define what type of object types can be passed to `add()`, and the problem with using `MyClass::class` as a parameter is that the value of that is a string, meaning I have to allow for strings to get passed in, so `new Main('bool')` is a valid, but nothing is an `instanceof` bool

Comment: Something like this: `public function __construct($type){
  if(class_exists($type))
   $this->type = $type;
  else $this->type = "default";
    }` ?

Comment: I feel that should be the correct answer @Rizier123, although I'm not sure how it works with autoloading (if it tries to load before or after).

Comment: @Rizier123 after testing that, it looks like it is working.

Comment: @MinusFour the second parameter of `class_exists` is an autoload parameter..

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Well... Your exemple seems okay to me. The output is expected to be right. What is wrong?

Comment: @felipsmartins what is wrong is that I can pass non-objects to the constructor

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn okay, so you desire pass any class to constructor but not scalar types, right? If so, it is not possible in PHP. Either set a type hint or set any types.

Comment: Just like on your code, instanceof would be the better way to go.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I've added an answear.

Comment: @felipsmartins I am using Rizer123's comment which works perfectly without having to create a Reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically it says that `add()` will only allow instances of `Test`.

It's possible to achieve this in `PHP` by simply adding the type before the argument name in the function definition (similar with `C`/`C++`/`C#` types):

```
class Main {
    protected $items = [];

    public function add(Test $object) {
        $this->items[] = $object;
    }
}
```

PHP 5 accepts [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) as [type hints](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration). If `Test` is a class then `Main::add()` accepts objects of class `Test` and its children. If `Test` is an interface, then the method `Main::add()` accepts objects that [implement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) `Test` or one of its children.

PHP 7 *(coming soon to a server near you)* [introduces](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) type hinting for scalar types too.

`PHP` does not support anything similar with `C++` templates or `C#` generics. If you want to create a class that works with objects of type `A` and another class that has identical behaviour but works with objects of type `B` you have several options but none of them is as elegant as the templates/generics:

1. Create two classes having identical behaviour, one for objects of type `A`, another for objects of type `B`; use different type hints (`A` and `B`) in the arguments lists of the methods of the two classes to enforce the separation - not scalable;
2. Something similar to your code, use the allowed class name as a string property and check it on any operation; you can also validate the argument of the constructor using [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) - the code becomes cluttered with tests and less readable;
3. Use OOP polymorphism; extend both `A` and `B` from the same class `T` or, even better, make `A` and `B` implement the same interface `I`. A PHP interface can be empty, it doesn't need to declare anything; empty interfaces used just for type hinting are common practice in PHP.

   Then write a single class `Main` and use `I` as type hint for all its methods that accept objects. It will accept objects of both types `A` and `B` but if you also declare functions in `I` (and implement them in `A` and `B`, of course) then use them in `Main` you can be sure nothing breaks (`I` becomes a contract between `Main` and the objects its accepts as arguments for its methods).

I would choose option #3 because it gets the most help from the interpreter; it verifies the type of the arguments on each function call that has type hints and triggers a recoverable fatal error (in PHP 5) or throws an exception (in PHP 7).

Also some IDEs and static code analysis tools can validate the calls without running the code and help you fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Php doesn't support template like declarations like e.g. c++.

The best way you may be able to achive this is by passing a lambda which then in return gets used in order to validate the passed parameter in add.

```
<?php
class Test {
    private $validator = null;

    public function __construct($validator) {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function add($value) {
        $func = $this->validator;
        $validated = $func($value);

        echo $validated ? 'OK' : 'NG';
    }
}

$obj = new Test(function($value) { 
    return is_int($value);
});

$obj->add(11);
$obj->add('string');
```

Another possibility would be to pass the type e.g. "ClassName" in your constructor and use `get_class()` and `gettype()` for the validation.

In the future there may be smarter solutions since you'll be able to write anonymous classes but I haven't really thought about that but in the end they would work similarly to lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make it so that the constructor only accepts class
>   types?

Nope!
It is not possible in PHP. Not like C#, at least.
You need either set a type hint or set any types.
However, there's a closer solution in order to accept only class when instancing a class: Using [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php)!

```
class Main {

    protected $items = [];
    protected $type  = null;

    public function __construct($type) {
        $reflector  = new ReflectionClass($type);
        $this->type = $reflector->getName(); # or: $this->type = $type;   
    }

    public function add($object) {       
        if($object instanceof $this->type) {
            $this->items[] = $object;                
        }        
    }    
}
```

As ReflectionClass contructor argument only accpets a string containing the name of the class to reflect, you can take advantage that, so passing scalars strings will cause an exception.

```
$main = new Main(Test::class); # Okay!
$main = new Main('Test');      # Okay!
```

However

```
$main = new Main('bool');
// Results
# PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' 
# with message 'Class bool does not exist' in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor to this:

```
public function __construct(Type $type){
    $this->type = $type;
}
```

This is based on the assumption that `$type` is an instance of `Type`.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm new to php, but isn't this answer correct?

Comment: It isn't a correct answer because the question is asking how to type hint dynamically.

Comment: @MinusFour Oh, now that I see his C# examples, it seems like he wants something like generics

Comment: That will only allow for `Type`, it wont allow for `Awesome` or `Amazing` as class types

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Unless all classes implements the `Interface` Type.